# Trouble showing text over images in slick gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, gallery

I am having trouble adding text over multiple images in a "Slick" gallery. I can get the text that I want to show on the first image of the gallery but when adding the text to the other slides they only appear on the first slide.

I used the following css for the text overlay:

```
.classTextOver{
  position: absolute;
   font-size: 16px;
   color: white;
   top:60%;
  left:18%;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

You can find the code snippet here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dkxq3ztg/1/

Answer (score 0):

This answer looks like it might create other issues for the slideshow, but if you use relative positioning, you can fix the text problem. Replace your .ClassTextOver with this:

```
.classTextOver {
position: relative;
top: 300px;
font-size: 40px;
color: white;
font-family: 'champion';
font-weight:normal;
left:100px;
}
```